# Double tap bar button item to scroll to the top

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I want to scroll to the top when i double tap on any `BarButtonItem`.
I saw a lot of answers on stackOverflow but none of them worked for me.
Maybe I'm using it wrong? Where do i put the code in the `AppDelegate` or the `TableViewControllers` i want to add this functionality specifically?

anyway, I'm using Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8 and would love to get some help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about `scrollsToTop`? I think it is what you need. Description from iOS SDK related to `scrollsToTop` property in `UIScrollView`:

> When the user taps the status bar, the scroll view beneath the touch which is closest to the status bar will be scrolled to top, but only if its `scrollsToTop` property is YES, its delegate does not return NO from `shouldScrollViewScrollToTop`, and it is not already at the top.
>       // On iPhone, we execute this gesture only if there's one on-screen scroll view with `scrollsToTop` == YES. If more than one is found, none will be scrolled.

Comment: Yea i know this line i saw it in many answers but i always got errors pointing on it as well.Can you maybe show me how to write it correctly to make it work?

Comment: `scrollsToTop` is true by default, but if you have many `UIScrollView` or it subclasses, you need to set `false` for all except needed view

Comment: The only 1 `UIScrollView` i have is this : `override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        self.searchController.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }` so i can swipe to dismiss the keyboard when i search...

Comment: Can you help me write the code so i can achieve the result i want? I have no idea how to do this properly :\

Answer (score 0):

At first setup UITabBarControllerDelegate delegate. Delegate can be easily set from Storyboard or via code with UITabBarController's delegate property.

```
myTabBar.delegate = myNewDelegate // Have to conform to UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol
```

You can even subclass UITabBarController and implement UITabBarControllerDelegate for it so it can become delegate for itself.

```
mySubclassedTabBar.delegate = mySubclassedTabBar
```

When you have delegate you can try out this method.

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
{
    guard let tabBarControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers
    else
    {
        // TabBar have no configured controllers
        return true
    }

    if let newIndex = tabBarControllers.indexOf(viewController) where newIndex == tabBarController.selectedIndex
    {
        // Index won't change so we can scroll

        guard let tableViewController = viewController as? UITableViewController // Or any other condition
        else
        {
            // We are not in UITableViewController
            return true
        }

        tableViewController.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I put all the code in the TableViewController/ViewController i want to add this functionality specifically? or in a new swift file i will make connected to my tabBarViewController?

Comment: Easiest way would be to subclass UITabBarController (so usually new swift file), implement delegate protocol and in storyboard change tabBarController's class. Then you can easily change delegate property in storyboard or via code (i.e. during initialisation).

Answer (score 0):

```
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if tabBarController.viewControllers!.firstIndex(of: viewController) == 0 {
        if self.selectedIndex != 0 { return true }

        if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController{
            if let streamController = navigationController.viewControllers.last as? HomeVC
            {
                streamController.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)

            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return true
}
```